# From numpy matrix to C array. Segmentation fault (memory corruption) on 64bit architecture

Tags: c, numpy

I'm trying to build up a python C extension in order to pass a numpy matrix to a C array. I was following the suggestions reported here:

http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/C_Extensions/NumPy_arrays

but when Python tries to run the C line:

```
v=(float **)malloc((size_t) (n*sizeof(float)));
```

of the follow portion of code:

```
float **_ptrvector(long n) { 
    float **v;
    v=(float **)malloc((size_t) (n*sizeof(float)));
    if (!v)   {
        printf("In **ptrvector. Allocation of memory for array failed.");
        exit(0); }
    return v;
}

float **pymatrix_to_carray(PyArrayObject *arrayin)  {
    float **c, *a;
    int i,n,m;

    n = PyArray_DIM(arrayin, 0);
    m = PyArray_DIM(arrayin, 1);
    c=_ptrvector(n);
    a = (float*) PyArray_DATA(arrayin);
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++)  {
        c[i]=a+i*m;  }  
    return c;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault on my Linux 64 bit machine. The problem is that this code works perfectly on 32 bit machines (both Windows and Linux). Moreover sizeof(size_t) returns correctly 4 on 32bit machines and 8 on 64bit machines. I'm using Python 2.7.1 [EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)] and GCC 4.1.2 on a Red Hat Linux 4.2.1-44 with kernel version 2.6.18.

I tried also with npy_intp and also Py_ssize_t instead of size_t but no positive effect.

Comment: if you're not a kernel, libc or compiler hacker, you should use a trailing instead of preceding underscore to mark private symbols

Comment: Numpy arrays are **not** guaranteed to be contiguous in memory. Also I think there already is a numpy C-Api function to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you want to allocate memory for pointers to `float`:

```
float **v;
v=(float **)malloc((size_t) (n*sizeof(float)));
```

but you do allocated memory for `float`s themselfes. On a 32bit system pointers need 4 bytes, so this works.

On a 64bit system pointers need 8 byte, so you might like to change the above line to be:

```
float ** v = malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
```

or even more secure to

```
float ** v = malloc(n * sizeof(*v));
```

---

Btw: In C it is not needed to caste the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc` nor is it recommended. Even more it is dangerous to do so as it might hide awful mistakes.

Comment: Valid point; but OP said the crash occurred _at the malloc_; you point out that using the space pointed to by `v` will quickly result in a crash. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Floris: From my experience `malloc()` itself only crashes if prior to calling it the memory managment (MM) got corrupted in any way, most propably by writing to unallocated memory and with this destroying/corrupting the MM's internal data structures. Imagine the OP's code in a loop: The first iteration would corrupt the MM, the second iteration's call to `malloc()` then could easily crash the app.

Comment: However, I strongly recommend to fix the issue pointed out by my answer and re-test.

Comment: Makes sense - the real problem may have happened elsewhere (for the same reason), or in an earlier pass through this code; the crash occurs when malloc is called again when the heap is corrupted. That makes a ton of sense. Agree it is a serious and fatal flaw in the code.

Comment: I checked and now everything is working thanks to the suggestion of alk.

Comment: @user2660761: Nice to read this. So if this answer answered your question it might be a good idea mark it as such by clicking the check mark above.